# Overheads in fetching many (500K) rows for a partitionID in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'd like to understand what are the overheads involved when a large number of rows which are sequentially stored in disk are fetched in Cassandra (v1.2).

With the following schema:

- TimeStamp
- Device ID
- Device Name
- Device Owner
- Device Color

PKEY (TimeStamp, DeviceID).
 
Each record is 80 bytes.

I’m trying to fetch all the rows for a particular TimeStamp (partitionID).

Select * from schema where TimeStamp = ‘…’

There are 500K such rows per timestamp. I have figured out that doing pagination would give a much better throughput than trying to fetch all in one shot. So to fetch 500 K rows (40 MB), using page size of 1000 / 10000, it took around 25-30 seconds (I'm using Astyanax). I have following questions:

(A) Will all the data that I’m querying be stored sequentially in disk for a particular TimeStamp (and yes, I’ve run compact command)?

(B) If answer to first qn is yes, then why am I not able to get throughput equal to disk (40 MB/s)? Please note that I’m able to retrieve 40 MB worth of data in 25-30 seconds, which translates to hardly 1.5 MB/s.

(C) If answer to above first question is yes, then could I further speed up the response?

(D) Is serialization / deserialization the culprit for slow throughput? If so, can something be done to avoid it altogether?

Answer (score 0):

A) it depends on the partitioner you have configured for the cluster (in the cassandra.yaml file) since you are new you are probably using the one that comes by default (MurMur3Partitioner) which means that the answer to your question is no, the data is splited amonsgt different nodes (or virtual nodes) inside 1 or more physical nodes, which mean that the data is stored in different parts on disk and on different physical nodes.

B) answer to A was no, so probably no

C) answer to B was no, still you should be able to time different queries and detect bottlenecks to improve speed. Use cqlsh after running this command:

cqlsh> tracing on
Now tracing requests.

and run the query/queries you want to check and see the different interactions between the nodes. You can use this to check if a fiven partitionID is stored in the way you need it when using the ButeOrderedPartitioner

D) it shouldn't be a problem, but just in case run the same query on cqlsh with tracing to time the requests as explained in C

Hope it helps!